# Virtual function input Argument type

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, c++14, pure-virtual

I am trying to understand inheritance and polymorphism. When I run this :

```
    #include<iostream> 
    using namespace std; 

class Base 
{ 
int x; 
public: 
    virtual Base* fun() = 0; 
    int getX() { return x; } 
}; 

// This class inherits from Base and implements fun() 
class Derived: public Base 
{ 
    
public: 
    int y;
    Derived* fun() { 
        Derived *d = new Derived;
        d->y = 2;
        return d;
        
    } 
}; 

int main(void) 
{ 
    Derived d;
    Derived *p = d.fun();
  cout<< p->y;
}
```

This works fine as  it is legal for a derived class to override a virtual function using a different return type as long as the return type is covariant with the original return type

But what if the virtual function contain the input argument of type `Base*`. Like :

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Base 
{ 
int x; 
public: 
    virtual Base* fun(Base * t) = 0; 
    int getX() { return x; } 
}; 

// This class inherits from Base and implements fun() 
class Derived: public Base 
{ 
    
public: 
    int y;
    Derived* fun(Derived *t) { 
        Derived *d = new Derived;
        d->y = t->y;
        return d;
        
    } 
}; 

int main(void) 
{ 
    Derived d;
    Derived *p = d.fun();
  cout<< p->y;
}
```

This is throwing error `error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘Derived’ Derived *d = new Derived;` which I understand it means that compiler is not recognising the implementation of the virtual function and considering the class ``Derived``` as abstract.

So how can we override virtual function of this type ??
I tried to search it , but didn't find any reference. If similar question exists , let me know.
Thanks

Comment: It's not possible. You must override with the same function name and the same number and types of arguments.

Comment: add `override` keyword to the method to make sure you actually override and not overload.

Comment: Thanks @Yksisarvinen , I got it now , we can keep the argument as Base* but in the main function we can pass Derived* .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I needed this in my own code. I'd write the new derived class like this:

```
// This class inherits from Base and implements fun() 
class Derived: public Base 
{ 
    
public: 
    int y;
    Derived* fun(Base *t) { 
        Derived *d = new Derived;
        Derived* input = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(t);
        ASSERT(input);    // Cause the debug version to throw an exception so the error can be debugged
        if(input)
           d->y = t->y;
        else
           d->y = 0;    // Or the default of your choice. 
        return d;
        
    } 
};
```

This introduces a potential runtime error if the base type passed in is not the correct derived type. But I don't see a way to avoid it.

The other options I see are use templates. Where the derived type requires the derived type to be passed in. Or simply create a new function that takes the derived type as input and also overrides `fun(Base *t)`;

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Base
{
    int x;
public:
    virtual T* fun(T* t) = 0;
    int getX() { return x; }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{

public:
    int y;
    Derived() { y = 0; }
    Derived* fun(Derived* t) {
        Derived *d = new Derived;
        d->y = t->y;
        return d;

    }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Derived *d = new Derived;
    Derived * p = d->fun(d);
    cout << p->y;
    return 0;
}
```

test in visual studio 2019.